# Database role switch in sqlite 3

Tags: database, sqlite

I am working on some application (legacy code) which basically scans the device for songs and provides browsing.

Now, to improve performance of certain features, the requirement is to use 3 databases as shown below with roles :

[image]

I am using **sqlite3** and I am opening one database session and attaching the other two databases.

Now, if you fire SQL query, without alias name attached, say `SELECT * FROM songs;`, it picks the database with alias name **main**.

The legacy browser module has all SQL queries like that (without database alias name attached, and I can't change them, so they will keep using the database with alias name `main`.

The solution is to change the assign the alias name `main` to appropriate database,when required.

My question is :

1. Can I assign alias name **main** to attached databases (one at a time)? If yes, how?
2. Or is there any better solution so that I can alter the default DB used?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not possible to change the database name of an already-attached database (including `main`).

However, the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_attach.html) says:

> If two or more tables in different databases have the same name and the database-name prefix is not used on a table reference, then the table chosen is the one in the database that was least recently attached.

So what you could do is to open some empty database as the main database (just use `:memory:`), and attach the other three databases in the desired order.

Comment: One more question, I am writing to DB in process A and some process B can also read during this period. So suppose in process A, I detach and re-attach a database, the process B can try to read the same database during this time. Is there any chance, that the database got detached while process B was reading from it. I think this wouldn't happen because in DBs everything is serialized, i.e one step at a time, so B will read either after detaching or before detaching. Please tell me if I am wrong.

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button. (And why didn't you try it?)